# Class CreateTableName Not found php artisan

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

when i typed in console - `php artisan make:migration create_website_table --create=website`

than file created, I didn't edit anything and ran command `php artisan migrate`

now i want to rollback it and it says

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
>     Class 'CreateWebsiteTable' not found

The code of my migration Website class

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateWebsiteTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('website', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('website');
    }
}
```

Maybe there is some namespaces?

Comment: Try running "composer dump-autoload" from the root of your Laravel project

Answer (score 1):

Before you run `php artisan migrate`, run the following code
`composer dump-autoload`.

Infact, whenever you get `ClassNotFound` Exception, run the above command!